# accessing methods of composition

Tags: c++, oop

This question may be somewhat vague, but bear with me.

I have 3 classes in my project.
2 classes have a composition relationship with 1 class, that is, the 2 are part of the 1.

however I must have access to the 2 classes methods, but don't really want to make them totally public.

in the 1 class i have the 2 classes instantiated with private visibility, which prevents the 1 class object from accessing the 2 class methods

This is in C++;)

EDIT: i'll put an example of what i have;

```
class Aclass
{
    private: int numA;
    public: void ExampleMethod();
};

class Bclass
{
    private: int numB;
    public: void ExampleMethodB();
};

class Cclass
{
    private: 
             Aclass Aobject;
             Bclass Bobject;
    public: 
};

void main()
{
    Cclass Cobject;

    Cobject.ExampleMethod();
}
```

Comment: What is the actual *question*?#

Comment: ExampleMethod() is not defined in Cclass. Eh?

Comment: right, i see my mistake on that example, but the point is i wish to access examplemethod() from the public interface of the Cobject

Answer (score 2):

> in the 1 class i have the 2 classes instantiated with private visibility, which prevents the 1 class object from accessing the 2 class methods

Your assumption is wrong. If the two objects are `private`, you can still access them from inside the class:

```
class A
{
public:
   foo();
};

class B
{
private:
   A a;
public:
   void goo() { a.foo(); } // this is ok, although a is private
                           // you can't access a from outside the class though
};
```

Comment: I wish to access the methods from outside the class though.

Comment: @andrewPatterson so how is composition related to the question?

Comment: well i believed it was composition?